# RegEx: Match characters between two strings

Tags: regex, expression

I'm trying to create a program that can parse a vpn log file and let user's know what is wrong with their VPN configuration. The VPN generates a html file that contains a lot of information which can be used to troubleshoot the problem. The issue is this information is too technical for the average user. Part of my process is to determine what the user's IP configuration looks like. The logs are capture at a point in time when they are off site so just gathering this information from various .net classes is not possible. I need to parse the log that is generated by the VPN that users attach to help tickets.

Here is a sample of the log file. I'm trying to gather all of the IP information for the Wireless adapter/ Ethernet adapter, teredo and ip-https adatpers. I'm first trying to gather information on the ethernet adapter using this regex which I can then filter these results down further with more regular expressions.

```
(Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:)(.*)(Auto)
```

The problem is this matches all the way down to the line Autoconfiguration under "Tunnel adapter". I can't figure out how to get the match to stop at the first Autoconfiguration if finds under Ethernet adapter local area connection.  I have my . set to match newlines as well.

```
Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : M-CNU3489QF5
Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : some.site.com
Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : some.site.com
                                   other.site.com

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 2:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : C4-D9-87-25-7B-F6
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : C4-D9-87-25-7B-F9
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6235
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : C4-D9-87-25-7B-F5
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::d4ac:bfab:e226:b235%12(Preferred) 
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.4(Preferred) 
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, August 17, 2014 5:35:30 PM
Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Monday, August 18, 2014 10:12:24 AM
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 247781767
DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1A-38-F2-60-A0-D3-C1-99-F9-EC
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : A0-D3-C1-99-F9-EC
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:c00c:509a:28e1:3b50:bbd7:84ae(Preferred) 
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::28e1:3b50:bbd7:84ae%15(Preferred) 
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter 6TO4 Adapter:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft 6to4 Adapter
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter iphttpsinterface:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : iphttpsinterface
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2HIDDNE3(Preferred) 
Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2HIDDEN3(Preferred) 
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::7023:b4d6:8ef7:d253%19(Preferred) 
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 
NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

Comment: Have you tried making it non-greedy? `(Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:)(.*?)(Auto)`

Comment: Yes you need to use the question mark quantifier after `*` to match the minimum amount.

Comment: (Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:)(.*?)(Auto) This did the trick thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'll have a go at forming a regex for this...

```
/((^[a-zA-Z0-9 -~]+?):\n{2}([a-zA-Z0-9 -~]+?))\n/gm
```

This does the following:

- Lazily match the start of a line with the characters a-z, A-Z, 0-9 or any printable unicode character between  and ~, followed by a colon
- You know there's 2 new lines after each block title so match that
- Lazily match the following paragraph from a-z, A-Z, 0-9, whitespace or any printable unicode character between  and ~ until a new line, then the block is finished.

There are probably a number of more complex regex techniques to match that but you should get the groups from that string, any then be able to select which number of the group you want. e.g: https://regex101.com/r/bI7zW2/1